# Is one DNA molecule same as one chromosome

Tags: molecular-genetics

Is one DNA molecule = one chromosome or is one DNA molecule = all the chromosomes, ie, all the genetic material in our cells? I have googled it but  I am not getting clear answers ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the [encyclopedic definition](https://www.britannica.com/science/molecule) of a molecule...

> Molecules are held together by shared electron pairs, or covalent bonds.

...one DNA molecule is one DNA strand.

Put another way, one DNA molecule is a polymer of [nucleotides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleoside_triphosphate#Naming) connected by [phosphodiester bonds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphodiester_bond). This means that one intact **double-stranded** chromosome is composed of **two** molecules of DNA interacting by hydrogen bonds.

In practice, however, one piece of double-stranded DNA is commonly called a DNA molecule.

All of the chromosomes in a cell constitute a single *genome*.

To further add to the confusion, identical [chromatids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatid) may be said to compose a single chromosome, such that one replicated chromosome composed of two chromatids may comprise **four** DNA molecules, by the definition outlined above.

---

Note, the [same encyclopedia](https://www.britannica.com/science/polarity-chemistry) lists ionic bonds as being on the same "continuum" as covalent bonds...

> Ionic and covalent bonding therefore can be regarded as constituting a continuum rather than as alternatives.

...so atoms held together in ionic interactions are also considered molecules, by this definition.